# External link from custom fields on a specific page

Tags: wordpress

I want to have one page with the list with titles of posts. And every title should link to external page (using custom field named 'link'). I have this code, but it changes the link everywhere on the site and I want it to work only on a specific page, let's say on a page named "Example". On a homepage and everywhere except the page "Example" it should link to the post.

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'links', 10, 2 );
function links( $link, $post )
{
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link', TRUE );
$url = esc_url( filter_var( $meta, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) );
return $url ? $url : $link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for **queried_object** on global **$wp_query**;

```
  add_filter( 'post_link', 'links', 10, 2 );
    function links( $link, $post )
    {
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link', TRUE );
    $url = esc_url( filter_var( $meta, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) );
    if($wp_query->queried_object instanceof WP_Post && $wp_query->queried_object->ID == 258){
        return $url ? $url : $link;
    }else{
        return $link;
    }

}
```

Comment: When I activate plugin with this code, the message appears:

"The plugin generated 4 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."